# Which is the best way to code App Javascript using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using it this way, still i'm getting an error that i'm going to paste below.
I'm testing it using Android 4.1.2, on my Motorola Razr.
Pretty much this is it.
Aw, another point, if i try to use 'this.buscarServidores' inside App.onDeviceReady is return an error saying that there's no such thing on 'this'.
HELP! ;(

```
var App = {
initialize: function() {
    App.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', App.onDeviceReady(), false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    dB = App.getDB();
    dB.transaction(App.populateDB, App.errorDB, App.buscarServidores);
},
getDB: function() {
    if (typeof this.dB === 'undefined') {
        this.dB = window.openDatabase("mysqlnavigator", "1.0", "MySQL Navigator", 10000000);
    }
    return App.dB;
},
errorDB: function(err) {
    alert("Erro (" + err.code + "): BANCO DE DADOS");
    console.log(err.message);
},
populateDB: function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servidores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, host TEXT, porta TEXT, usuario TEXT, senha TEXT, ultimologin TEXT)");
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO servidores (host, porta, usuario, senha) VALUES ('jorgeferrari.com.br', '3306', 'jorgefer_and', '321654987');");
    console.log("Databases Populated");
},
buscarServidores: function() {
    db = App.getDB();
    db.transaction(App.txBuscaServidores, App.errorDB);
},
txBuscarServidores: function(tx) {
    console.log('txBuscarServidores');
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM servidores", [], sBuscaServidores, errorDB);
},
sBuscaServidores: function(tx, resultados) {
    console.log('sBuscaServidores');
    if (resultados.rows.length > 0) {
        var txResultados = '';
        for (i = 0; i < resultados.rows.length; i++) {
            txResultados += resultados.rows.item(i).host + ":" + resultados.rows.item(i).porta + "<br/>";
        }
        $('.resultados').html(txResultados);
    } else {
        $('.resultados').html("Nenhum resultado encontrado");
    }
},
dB: undefined
};
```

The error i'm getting is this one:

```
02-28 10:18:44.638 10128 10128 D CordovaLog: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 25 : Databases Populated
02-28 10:18:44.708 10128 10128 D CordovaLog: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 29 : Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17
```

Line 29 would be:

```
db.transaction(App.txBuscaServidores, App.errorDB);
```

EDIT
event if i prior using this instead of app inside the object, i get this error
    02-28 10:27:51.224 10289 10289 D CordovaLog: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 29 : Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistype error....

```
   db.transaction(App.txBuscaServidores, App.errorDB);
```

shold be

```
    db.transaction(App.txBuscarServidores, App.errorDB);
```